# Rails - how to set a custom default date format for the current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date-format

I have a `date_format` field in my `User` model, which contains a string such as `%m/%d/%y` or `%d/%m/%y` etc.

I would like the app to display dates in whatever format the current user has set in their `date_format` field.

I'm currently trying this, but to no avail:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :user_date_format, if: :current_user

private
  def user_date_format
    Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]=current_user.date_format
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work because it's changing the default format for all users, not just the current user.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
What other ways can we change the default date format, *for the current request only* - i.e. so it won't interfere with any other requests that may be in place.

Answer (score 2):

`Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]` is a class variable which is loaded into the Rails app memory and stays there unless changed. When you change it for a user, it stays changed even after that user logs out. It is only changed when another user logs in. So you can define a default format and fall to that if no user is logged in. Smting like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :user_date_format

private
  def user_date_format
    Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]=  current_user.try(:date_format) || "%d/%m/%y"
  end
end
```

Now when a user logs in the format would be set to their settings. If this user signs out and an anonymous user (or a user with no date format seeting) accesses the app, the format defaults to `%d/%m/%y`

Comment: I think what I'm trying to say is that changing `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]` is not safe, and is not the correct way to do what I'm after. There must be another way to change the default date format for just the current request, that won't effect any other requests?

Comment: other option is to use a helper method `def display_date(d) d.strftime(current_user.date_format) end`. This needs you to change the code wherever a date is displayed in the views.

Comment: Yeah OK, I guess that's what I'll have to do for now. Pity there's not a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: ya, it is something I have wondered, a way to set global settings/variables per request. Only way I know is to define a before filter and make sure to initialize them for every request.